# Libgdx Using a click listener on multiple images (looping)

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, clicklistener

I was wondering is there a way to set multiple images using a click listener that are grouped together. I have this array of Images and I tried to use an enhanced for each loop but it didn't work. I'm trying to set a click listener on all the images in an array without individually setting each member of the array with a click listener.

EDIT

```
public  void Player1() {
    deck.displayHand();

    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    group.addActor(deck.hand.get(0));
    deck.hand.get(0).setPosition(200,0);
    deck.hand.get(0).setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    group.addActor(deck.hand.get(1));
    deck.hand.get(1).setPosition(220,0);
    deck.hand.get(1).setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    group.addActor(deck.hand.get(2));
    deck.hand.get(2).setPosition(240,0);
    deck.hand.get(2).setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

 stage.addActor(group);

    rand = (int) (Math.random() * (deck.hand.size));

    for (int z = 0; z<deck.hand.size; z++){
        final int finalZ = z;
        deck.hand.get(z).addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                deck.hand.get(finalZ).addAction(Actions.moveTo(300,400));
            }
        });
    }


}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}}
```

Do I have to use an enhanced for each loop or is it possible to use a different loop? The aim is for the user to click/touch one of the images and it would go to one location of the screen, for every image clicked/touch it would go to one location on the screen.

Comment: Why didn't it work? You get a exception or does the clicking not work in which case you probably need to call `stage.act()` in your update method and set the stage as a input processor `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)`.

Comment: I called stage.act and set my stage as my input processor but I still can't click on the images

Comment: Well, in your code you are setting the images on stage and gave them a `ClickListener` so as far as I can tell there is something else going on but I need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is like a puzzle sort of thing, you could use a counter that increments in the size of each image and put that as the position. That makes very little sense so here:

```
// Fill array with each image in it's grid position e.g. the bottom left image would go at (0, 0) in the array.
Image[][] array = new Image[cols][rows];

// All the images have to be the same size but not necessarily square.
imageWidth = 100;
imageHeight = 100;

for(int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < array[0].length; x++) {
        Image img = array[y][x];
        img.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                img.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x * imageWidth + initialXOffset, y * imageHeight + initialYOffset));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This only works if the images are all the same size.**

Comment: Imagine the concept as images of food (fruits) that are found at the bottom of the screen (all aligned on the x-axis), instead of setting a click listener on each fruit I want to loop the click listener once on the array of fruits so when I want to add a different fruit to the array it would automatically have a click listener and each member of the fruit array also would have a click listener.